# JDK x64 and JRE x86 application open

Tags: java, eclipse

If I have JDK x64 installed and I make application, can I run it with JRE x86, or it just compiles application to be x64? Also can I run eclipse x64 with JDK x86, or eclipse x86 with JDK x64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java bytecode is platform-independent. Java code compiled with a 64-bit JDK works on a 32-bit JRE and vice versa - there is no difference in the bytecode.

You do not need to compile your Java code for 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download  and install JDK and JRE together, JDK installation package has it's own JRE installation inside. So you need to install JDK only so things won't get messy talking compatibility wise.